# Is there a way to sort bookmarks by domain in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way to do this? Only way I found in Google Chrome is by the bookmarks name, not domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 extensions for that: "IO BookBar" and "SuperSorter".

First you use "IO Bookbar" to strip away all bookmark titles.
Then you use "SuperSorter" to sort them. Since they don't have any title, they will be sorted by domain name.

Another solution is to prefix your bookmark titles manually, with the domain name or a short version of that.

Answer (score 1):

there is sprucemark ([chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sprucemarks/fakeocdnmmmnokabaiflppclocckihoj), [github](https://github.com/ForestMist/sprucemarks)) which have feature to sort by url

[image: image on sort option]

but it will sort by url, so if you have url with different scheme (http vs https) it will be sorted differently

Answer (score -1):

Goto:

```
chrome://bookmarks
```

and click on "Organize", there is a menu option called "Reorder by title"

Comment: OP wants to sort by domain, not title.